# ADsPath and LDAP path string

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ads

I've been using LDAP for a while now to bind with Active Directory using System.DirectoryServices.
 I came across multiple ways to bind to an AD object using this ldap Paths:
What are the differences between them?

**LDAP://parentdomain.com/CN=user,OU=myou,DC=childdomain,DC=parentdomain,DC=com**
Works from all domain controllers but not from a remote binding

**LDAP://childdomain.parentdomain.com/CN=user,OU=myou,DC=childdomain,DC=parentdomain,DC=com**
Works from both domain controllers and remote bindings

**LDAP://childdomain2.parentdomain.com/CN=user,OU=myou,DC=childdomain,DC=parentdomain,DC=com**
Works from all domain controllers but not from a remote binding

*Notice the diffidence in the server side of the LDAP path*

I'm a bit confused, why can I bind with a domain controller different than the domain controller of the AD object in any domain controller that belongs to the same forest but not remotely.

I hope it sounds clear

Comment: Are you sure your LDAP paths are all correct  Please double-check them one more time.

Comment: I believe you can connect to parent dc and get an object from child dc when referral chasing is used https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa746453(v=vs.85).aspx. What do you mean by remote binding? Binding from a machine, that joined to a parent domain or from a standalone workstation? Anyway, the best practice is to bind to the domain/dc that the object belongs to. If you want to query objects from the entire forest perform all searches on a global catalog

Comment: @T-Heron Yes I'm sure of the LDAP paths... oldovets I mean a standalone workstation, also, I believe a global catalog is the way to go. I read this article about cross-references where all domain controllers store informations about other dc in the same forest.... https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783351(v=ws.10).aspx#w2k3tr_logic_how_zlqt